# Hailstone Sequence in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sequence

```
length = 0
for n in range(1,101):
    print "Sequence #:", n
    while n != 1:
        print n,
        if n % 2 == 0:
           n = n / 2
           length = length + 1
        else:
            n = (n * 3) + 1
            length = length + 1
        if n == 1:
            print n
            length = length + 1
    print "The sequence above contains", length, "numbers"
    length = 0
```

## My Problem:

The python code above calculates the hailstone sequence for numbers 1 - 100 and displays the length of the sequence afterwards. How can I display the number with the longest sequence and its corresponding length after all calculations are done?

Comment: a side note...you do realize the value of n in the forloop is not changed when you do `n=whatever` (although the value of n for the while loop is changed) right?

Comment: Add two variables, one for the current candidate, the other for the associated  sequence length.  Work out the detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will keep track of the max length and sequence and display them at the end. The lines marked with a `##` are the additions to your original code.

```
length = 0
max_length = 0 ##

for n in range(1,101):
    print "Sequence #:", n
    seq = [] ##
    while n != 1:
        print n,
        seq.append(n)  ##
        if n % 2 == 0:
           n = n / 2
           length = length + 1
        else:
            n = (n * 3) + 1
            length = length + 1
        if n == 1:
            print n
            seq.append(n) ##
            length = length + 1
    print "The sequence above contains", length, "numbers"

    if length > max_length:  ##
        max_length = length  ##
        max_seq = seq[:]     ##

    length = 0

print 'max length: ', max_length ## same as len(max_seq)
print 'max seq: ', max_seq       ##
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save the results for each input and look for the longest in the end.

```
results = []
length = 0
for n in range(1,101):
    print "Sequence #:", n
    while n != 1:
        print n,
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n / 2
            length = length + 1
        else:
            n = (n * 3) + 1
            length = length + 1
        if n == 1:
            print n
            length = length + 1
    results.append((n,length))
    print "The sequence above contains", length, "numbers"
    length = 0
print 'Longest sequence of lenght {1} found for number {0}'.format(*max(results, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```